# Can I have an instafrag match in Counter Strike: Source?

Tags: counter-strike-source

Is it possible in counter strike source to increase weapon-damage (in a bot-match) so that everyone gets one-shot kills?

Comment: You're going to need to clarify a bit. Are you asking for a server mod that makes all weapons a one-hit kill? Or a client-side hack?

Comment: client side would be preferred

Comment: So you're basically asking for a cheat to a multiplayer game? I wouldn't expect much help.

Comment: erm no, somehow something got mixed up here. When I start a local game against bots I want that all players get weapons with maximum damage

Comment: @elhombre Well, that's why you should clarify what you're really trying to do. Maybe [edit] your question?

Comment: Did my edit now clarify the Question?

Comment: Not really.  Define "maximum damage", one-hit-kills?  Upper bound on any damage spread (not sure if there is any in CS)?  As though all shots were headshots or torso shots?  Define "all weapons", all of yours?  Everyone's?

Comment: I implemented your suggestions, how is it now?

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this client sided, or at least, legally. A client side modification would be a hack and in the event of attempting to do this you will likely get VAC'd.

You  need a *server side* plugin to do this for you.  Whether you create a local game on your computer or connect to one online, you are still playing in a *server* environment.  When you start a game on your computer it creates a server with your local IP and connects you to it.

The easiest way for you do do this for yourself playing with bots would be to **install [Sourcemod](http://www.sourcemod.net/) in your cstrike folder.** It's in `steam>steamapps>yourname>counter strike source>cstrike`

There you will create a `addons` folder, inwhich you will put sourcemod, metamod, metamod.vdf, etc.

After download this plugin and place it in the plugins folder. [[CSS] Weapon Mod](http://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=123015)

Set up the cvars/configuration files to your needs.  It looks like you're looking for:

```
genericdamage -- min value 0.0, max value 1000.0 -- Modifies damage done to the generic hitgroup. 0.0 stops the damage. This hitgroup is used by knife, grenade explosion and flashbang/smoke projectile physics damage.    
headdamage -- min value 0.0, max value 1000.0 -- Modifies damage done to the head hitgroup. 0.0 stops the damage.    
chestdamage -- min value 0.0, max value 1000.0 -- Modifies damage done to the chest hitgroup. 0.0 stops the damage.    
stomachdamage -- min value 0.0, max value 1000.0 -- Modifies damage done to the stomach hitgroup. 0.0 stops the damage.    
armdamage -- min value 0.0, max value 1000.0 -- Modifies damage done to both arm hitgroups. 0.0 stops the damage.    
legdamage -- min value 0.0, max value 1000.0 -- Modifies damage done to both leg hitgroups. 0.0 stops the damage.
```

Then once you create a local server the plugin will load and you'll have your damage.

Comment: +1 OP doesn't seem to understand that there *are* no single-player matches in CS:S - even when you are playing by yourself against bots, you are still creating a multiplayer-server and connecting to it (possibly both on the same computer).  Thus, what he's looking for is exactly this: a server-side plugin to increase damage.

Answer (score -3):

You should look at a headshot only script.  I think there will be something in it about this
since headshots do way more damage than they are supposed to do.

Comment: Won't always work. Helm still prevents a head-shot-kill.

Comment: well in most headshot only server they adjusted this in the server config so bullets deal more damage so if he can find 1 of those he prob has his answer

Comment: @ronnie: There is no such config.  Headshot-only servers use a serverside-plugin, like the one linked by stevether above.  Also, perhaps you should edit your answer - for CS, "script" usually refers to something client-side *(because there are no legal client-side "plugins")*, so "headshot-only script" sounds like you are recommending downloading hacks.

Comment: a script in my eyes normally refers to a buy script or such wich are fully legal however people of lower skills don't know this most of the time however plugins are also scripts... however you use these on your server so if he sets up his own server (which i think he means since else it would ofc be a hack however u can't change that in your own config) and why update my answer for CS? when it's about CSS...